# Execute js multiple times

Tags: html, ajax, symfony, webpack, webpack-4

​

I have a legacy **Symfony** application with globals about everywhere. I'm trying to use webpack. But I have this issue where I have buttons that send ajax request, fetching HTML pages (twig pages).

These pages have scripts. So the  way I've done it, is have the following entrypoints:

​

- Initial page: **EntrypointA.js**
- HTML page (fetched by an ajax request at runtime): **EntrypointB.js**

​

So here, I have few questions:

1. Is this the way to go (multiple entrypoints) for this scenario ?
2. If I fetch the HTML page multiple times, the entrypoint gets executed only once....Is there a way to avoid this ? And execute the entrypoint everytime it's fetched.

> **EntrypointB** has jquery code binding on dom elements that are present in the fetched HTML. So it must execute everytime
>
> I use `optimization: { runtimeChunk: 'single' }`  aswell, because files import in EntrypointA must have reference to some files in EntrypointB

​

Thanks

​

Comment: Note: After retrying to migrate to webpack again, it turns out the `optimization: { runtimeChunk: 'single' }` is the reason each module is executed only once as per [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/)

Unfortunately removing this optimization, causes issues with jquery and its plugins (basically jquery is included once, then another-jquery-plugin is included, then another file is including jquery, therefore overriding first version and another-jquery-plugin is no more available)

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is for bundling together stuff that is meant to go together (as a matter of fact only frontend part). All of JS for example into a single min file, all of CSS - the same, hash and organize images and some folders, etc. But from what you say it looks like you are trying to bundle unrelated things, like frontend JS and backend twig templates. It's ok to bundle JS (jQuery, some runtime scripts), but leave the templates alone.

Doesn't Symfony app have a backend router that will resolve your request to a corresponding twig template?

Comment: I'm not trying to bundle the twig template, but execute multiple times the script that's within the twig template.